# Is there something incorrect in this question?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

> Let G be a **bipartite graph** with two Groups A, B.
> Given: |A| =2, |B|=n and that there are edges that connect every single node in A
> with every node in B. Let T be a spanning tree of G, Prove that There
> is a node in B such that it's connected to both nodes in Group A in T.

**Why this is even true? I could take t to include 0 edges which says that the above claim is totally wrong.**

Comment: The tree has to be spanning (touch all vertices), so it cannot have zero edges.

Comment: is there a typo, should it be "edges that connect every node in **A** with every node in B"?

Comment: ah right... Can you give hint for proving this, (I am thinking of using contradiction)

Comment: Corrected thanks @DanUznanski

Comment: Isn't the graph in question just $K_{2, n}$ for some $n$?

Comment: and what is $K_{2,n}$?

Comment: $K_{2, n}$ is the complete bipartite graph with partite sets of size $2$ and $n$ respectively. To address your bolded question, please provide the definition of a spanning tree (hopefully this definition includes both what it means for a graph to be a *tree*, and what it means for a subgraph of a graph to be *spanning*).

Comment: You have a couple of answers now, Daniel. Any thoughts on them?

Comment: Come on, Daniel, it's not polite to ask a question and then run away. Please engage with the people who have tried to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{a_1, a_2\}.$ For $k=1,2$, let $B_k$ be the vertices of $B$ that are joined to $a_k$ in $T.$  Once you explain why the intersection of $B_1$  and $B_2$ can't be empty, you're done. (In particular, each $B_k$ is nonempty.)

Answer (score 1):

For $T$ to be a spanning tree, there must be a path in $T$ from one of the vertices in Group A to the other one. Think about what such a path must be.